# Shell script does not continue after openVPN command

Tags: bash, scripts, openvpn

I am trying to use a shell script to start an openVPN connection and mount a folder I can reach through that connection. (I don't know all too much about shell script).

So I created this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
openvpn --config /etc/openvpnconfig/openvpn.ovpn --auth-nocache --auth-retry none --replay-window 128 30 & pid=$!
if mountpoint -q /mnt/remote; then
  exit 0
else
  mount /mnt/remote
fi
```

When running this script it does not go past the openvpn call though. I thought the & would avoid this, since it gives access back when used in the terminal, but I guess I was wrong.

According to [Shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) the syntax should be fine.

Is there any way I can ensure that the script continues after openVPN is done initialising?

For Context: I want this script to be used by my Bacula Backup System and the connection is only supposed to be open as long as it is needed for backups. As a result executing openvpn and mount individually does not change the problem in this case.

Comment: What happens if you run the openvpn command with the & from a command prompt?  Does it create a job in the background and give you the prompt back?  Is it still connected to the terminal?  If so you could try separating it from the terminal using "at", for example `echo 'openvpn blah' | at now` but then you would have to use ps to get its process id.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the script from locking I decided to add the option

```
-daemon
```

to the openvpn call to seperate the actual openvpn operation from the script.

While this stops the openvpn output it at least allows the script to continue. I will look into sending the openvpn ouput into a log file later, if necessary.